# How to find record that not present in second table, Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a two table, Table A and Table B. Table A has many Table B means one to many relationship. I want to find those record of Table A that not in Table B. How can I find that record?

Thanks, In Advance

Comment: Any of the given solutions worked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ta.*
FROM TableA AS ta
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS tb
        ON ta.id = tb.fk
WHERE tb.fk IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `foreign_key` which is in the `table B` to do this

Lets Assume your table names as `states` and `countries` and the relation is `country has_many states` and `state belongs_to country`.So the `states` table will be having a `foriegn_key country_id`.

In ActiveRecord Way,do like the below

```
@country = Country.find(params[:id]) #the record of table A which you want to see if it exists in table B

@state = State.where(:country_id => @country.id)
```

If the `@state` returns `nil`,then there is `no such record` of `countries(table A)` in `states(table B)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Slyzz wrote:

```
TabelA.joins("left outer join table_bs on table_as.id = table_bs.table_as_id").where("table_bs.id" => nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

for future reference, you are using Rails 5 you can use the new left_outer_joins method:

```
ModelA.where(group_id: group_id)
      .left_outer_joins(:relation_in_model_a)
      .merge(ModelB.where(id: nil))
```